# USB keyboard is recognized as mouse, thus not working

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, keyboard

I attached a USB keyboard to my laptop today. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit. The keyboard isn't working. I looked in Control Panel/Hardware and Sound/Devices and Printers, and it turns out Windows thinks the USB keyboard is a USB mouse!

I'm not sure how to convince Windows the keyboard is actually a keyboard. I went into device management through Computer->Manage, and it's listed both under HID devices and as a mouse. I can uninstall the driver, but when it recognizes something was attached through USB, it will just recognize it as a mouse. I'm also not able to select the keyboard driver myself (through device manager -> update driver.), since it will automatically select the mouse drivers.

The USB keyboard is working when attached to a Windows XP desktop.

As requested, the device manager screenshot: 
[image]

The opened windows are of the keyboard which is recognized as a mouse.

The keyboard model: Dell KB212-B

Edit:
I replaced the above mentioned keyboard with a different one (Dell SK8115) and it's working.

Comment: Which brand and model number of keyboard? Can you show a screenshot of what you're seeing, for example the device manager with the keyboard and mouse items opened?

Comment: There should be just HID-compliant device under Human interface devices. There should be mouse specifically under the Mice and other pointing devices. Is it like that? Does it work on another pcs?

Comment: @Vitas : they keyboard is working when connected to a desktop. See the linked-to screenshot regarding the device manager.

Comment: I've inlined the image for you, though SE seems to have shrunk it down. Might help to view the image seperately if needed, or perhaps to crop the image (which I'll look at doing later if I remember)

Comment: Are you using some method to bypass the driver signing in order to install an older version of IBM's mouse pad drivers? Could you please open the properties for the driver, details, and select hardware IDs in the dropdown. Then give me the PID and VID values. (`xxxx` and `yyyy` in `HID\VID_xxxx&PID_yyyy`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic (non-reproducible) because the asker has been absent from this site for more than 5 years.